# Load in a corner an image in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm beginner in Python and Tkinter. I'm trying to put an image in the top-left corner but I couldn't. I was tried with the property "justify" and "Anchor". Here is my code:

```
logo_upb = PhotoImage(file="upb.gif")
label = Label(root, image=logo_upb, justify=LEFT)
label.image = logo_upb
label.place(bordermode=INSIDE, x=0, y=0)
label.pack()
```

I would be thankful with any solution.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried grid geometry manager.

The grid geometry manager puts the widgets in a 2-dimensional table. You’ll be surprised how much easier it is to use the grid manager instead of packer.

Lets take this example to show what grid can do. Creating this layout using the pack manager is possible, but it takes a number of extra frame widgets.

[image: tkinter grid example]

But with grid geometry manager you can also have the widgets span more than one cell. The `columnspan` option is used to let a widget span more than one column < checkbutton > and < image >, and the `rowspan` option lets it span more than one row < image >.

The following code creates the shown layout:

```
label1.grid(sticky=E)
label2.grid(sticky=E)

entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)
entry2.grid(row=1, column=1)

checkbutton.grid(columnspan=2, sticky=W)

image.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=2, rowspan=2,
           sticky=W+E+N+S, padx=5, pady=5)

button1.grid(row=2, column=2)
button2.grid(row=2, column=3)
```

So your answer will be identical to position of < label 1 > in other words grid would be `row = 0`, and `column = 1`.
Tkinter has native support for GIFs, so there is no need for additional library.

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
img = tk.PhotoImage(file ="somefile.gif")
panel = tk.Label(root, image = img)
panel.grid(row=0,column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

My personal recommendation is using Python Imaging Library (PIL) link: http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/ adding more supported files formats to the game. List of supported files formats: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pil/formats.html

In this example I used .jpg file format which is not natively supported in tkinter, and all  works perfectly because we are using PIL.

```
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

root = tk.Tk()
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("somefile.jpg"))
panel = tk.Label(root, image = img)
panel.grid(row=0,column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

**Warning:** Never mix grid and pack in the same master window. Tkinter will happily spend the rest of your lifetime trying to negotiate a solution that both managers are happy with. Instead of waiting, kill the application, and take another look at your code. A common mistake is to use the wrong parent for some of the widgets.

LINK: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm

Comment: In your example, you don't need PIL if all you're displaying is a GIF -- tkinter has native support for GIFs. Otherwise, excellent answer!

Comment: Personaly I always use PIL (which is btw. great library), so for example there could be "somefile.jpg" or "somefile.png" etc., and all would work perfectly in define resolution of supported file formats.[link] (http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pil/formats.html)       I will edit my answer for better understanding of this example...

Answer (score 0):

The specific reason for your problem is that you use place more-or-less correctly, then throw all that placement away when you call `pack()`. `place`, `pack` and `grid` aren't complimentary -- you must use only one to manage any particular widget.